# Flutter: How to set the background color behind the BouncingScrollPhysics on CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

i want a design like [image1](https://prnt.sc/4dJmbNfjL51C). I use CustomScrollView with BouncingScrollPhysics for iOS. I also use CupertinoSliverRefreshControl to refresh content.

My issue is that when I pull to refresh, the background color is (as expected) the background color of the Scaffold, but I need the color of the SliverAppBar.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Excepted:
[Image1](https://prnt.sc/4dJmbNfjL51C)

Issue:
[Image2](https://prnt.sc/iV2N1k_5FKRr)

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          const CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(),
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
            pinned: true,
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text("My titlte"),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.blue[800]!,
                    Colors.white,
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            height: 200,
                            child: const Center(
                              child: Text("Widget 1"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            height: 200,
                            child: const Center(
                              child: Text("Widget 2"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8)),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Placeholder(),
          ),
          const SliverFillRemaining(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need your appbar to be scrolled as well?

Comment: Set Scaffold's background color to Colors.blue[800],; Code : Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],

Comment: @DhanrajPriyadarshi Ιt doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Prashant If i set background color to Scaffold, then the rest of the widgets in the scrollview will have blue color, instead of default Scaffold color

Comment: Then wrap a Scaffold with existing Scaffold and give Blue color to first Scaffold and white color to Second Scaffold